# Setting up logging with PHP official docker image

Tags: php, logging, docker

I'm using the official [PHP docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) but don't quite know how to setup logging to work. I want to view my `error_log()` results in a file.

**Update**: I renamed `/usr/src/php/php.ini-development` to `/usr/src/php/php.ini` but I only see truncated logs using `docker logs`.

Comment: Why not set a custom error handler with set_error_handler() that stores errors in file?

Comment: I'm creating a WordPress plugin and would rather use PHP config to set this up.

Comment: Then check where is the PHP error log file (in PHP.INI) and use it. Set the error reporting to the desired level too. You can change the error log file location if you want. Check this article for more details http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/error_log-defines-file-where-script-errors-logged/

Comment: I have `error_log = /var/log/apache2/error.log` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` set.